# Правильное css , не понимаю как это реализовать

Tags: css

Как правильно составить hover без class ?
Есть два блока без id и class - при hover на второй он становится z-index 3 - пишу стиль через first-child и nth-child

```css
.wrapper{
  width:300px;
  height:100px;
  background:lightblue;
  position:relative;
  }
  .wrapper div:first-child{
    position:absolute;
    width:300px;
    height:100px;
    top:0; left:0;
    z-index:2;
    background:green;
  }
    .wrapper .div2{
    position:absolute;
    width:300px;
    height:100px;
    top:0; left:0;
    z-index:1;
    background:red;
    display:none;
  }
  .wrapper div:hover .wrapper div:nth-child(2){
    display:block;
    z-index:3;
  }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div> 
  <p>Наведи на меня</p>
  </div>
  <div> 
  <p>Вот он я скрытый текст </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

на jsfiddle с class работает https://jsfiddle.net/atlanta/zydubfhb/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/LLfq4hjj/

Comment: ответом сделайте -

Comment: чего там ответом делать, у вас там одна по сти дела опечатка

Comment: какая ошибка  была ?

Comment: я только одно поменял - `.wrapper .div2{` на `.wrapper div:nth-child(2)` и выбросил классы

Comment: но ответ сделай - такие правила здесь - я поставлю его лучшим

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы хотите работать без классов, то  и замените класс на селектор `.wrapper .div2{` на .wrapper `div:nth-child(2)`

```
.wrapper div:nth-child(2){
....
```

[Рабочий пример](https://jsfiddle.net/LLfq4hjj/)